# Junção de tabelas

Tags: join, tabela-html

Tenho três tabelas uma chamada  `CRM_PROCESSO`, outra chamada `CRM_PROCESSO_VARIAVEL` e a ultima chamada `CRM_PROCESSO_ATIVIDADE`, ambas possuem a variável **`idprocesso`** em comum.

O que preciso é que o comando traga o campo `IDPROCESSO`, `USUARIO`, `DATAINICIO`, `DATATERMINO` da tabela `CRM_PROCESSO`,o campo `DESCRICAO` da tabela `CRM_PROCESSO_ATIVIDADE`e o campo `valoratual`da tabela `CRM_PROCESSO_VARIAVEL`

Consegui fazer o comando, porém com os dados separados.

Rodei o comando abaixo, e trouxe o campo `IDPROCESSO`, `USUARIO`, `DATAINICIO`, `DATATERMINO` da tabela `CRM_PROCESSO`,o campo `DESCRICAO` da tabela `CRM_PROCESSO_ATIVIDADE`, quando ambas tem o `IDPROCESSO` igual.

```
    select crm_processo.idprocesso,
       crm_processo.usuario,
       crm_processo.datainicio,
       crm_processo.datatermino,
       crm_processo_atividade.descricao  
   from crm_processo join crm_processo_atividade on (crm_processo_atividade.idprocesso = crm_processo.idprocesso and crm_processo_atividade.idatividade = crm_processo.idatividadeatual) where status = 1 and idprocedimento = 34 and idatividadeatual <>2
```

E consegui fazer o comando abaixo, trazendo o campo `valoratual`da tabela `CRM_PROCESSO_VARIAVEL` *(Utilizei um exemplo com IDPROCESSO = 39)*

```
SELECT  cpv.descricao, 
cpv.valoratual,
(CASE CPV.DESCRICAO
     WHEN '/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/' THEN 'Motivo Cancelamento'
     END)  from crm_processo_variavel cpv  where idprocesso = 3089 AND CPV.DESCRICAO IN ('/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/')
```

Mas sinceramente, não sei como juntar os dois comando.

A relação processo x atividade é 1 para 1.
E processo x variável também 1 para 1.

Alguém consegue me auxiliar ?

Comment: A relação processo x atividade é `1 para 1`? E processo x variável também `1 para 1`? Ou é `1 para 0`, ou `1 para muitos`? É importante saber a multiplicidade das relações para você saber se você vai fazer um JOIN ou um OUTER JOIN para recuperar os registros em uma consulta única. Edite a pergunta e informe as multiplicidades.

Comment: Olá @Pagotti a relação processo x atividade é 1 para 1. E processo x variável também 1 para 1.

Comment: Tem algo estranho porque na sua query original tem `crm_processo_atividade.idatividade = crm_processo.idatividadeatual`. Se é `1 para 1` porque você tem esse `idatividadeatual`? Cada processo pode ter mais de 1 atividade?

Comment: O `crm_processo_variavel` também tem um filtro da descrição. Isso significa que cada `crm_processo_variavel` também é `1 para muitos`? E você está aplicando os filtros para que resulte apenas 1 registro de processo. É isso?

Comment: Uma ferramenta legal que você pode usar quando tiver questões desse tipo é o [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com). Lá você pode colocar a estrutura e dados de exemplo das tabelas e depois compartilhar na pergunta para facilitar quem for te ajudar. Coloque nas tags também qual é o banco que você está usando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a relação é `1 para 1` entre as três tabelas, então bastaria um `JOIN` normal entre elas, mas pelos comentários parece que a relação é `1 para N` e os filtros nas tabelas forçam uma relação `1 para 1`. Nesse caso você pode fazer o filtro no `JOIN` ou criando `SUBQUERY` com filtros internos.

A versão com filtro no `JOIN` é essa:

```
SELECT P.idprocesso,
       P.usuario,
       P.datainicio,
       P.datatermino,
       PA.descricao AS pa_descricao,
       PV.valoratual,  
       CASE PV.descricao 
         WHEN '/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/' THEN 'Motivo Cancelamento'     
         END AS pv_descricao
FROM crm_processo AS P 
LEFT JOIN crm_processo_atividade AS PA
     ON PA.idprocesso = P.idprocesso
     AND idatividade = P.idatividadeatual
     AND idatividade <> 2
LEFT JOIN crm_processo_variavel AS PV
     ON PV.idprocesso = P.idprocesso
     AND PV.descricao IN ('/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/')
WHERE 
     P.status = 1 
     AND P.idprocedimento = 34
```

A versão com `SUBQUERY` é essa:

```
SELECT P.idprocesso,
       P.usuario,
       P.datainicio,
       P.datatermino,
       PA.descricao AS pa_descricao,
       PV.descricao AS pv_descricao,
       PV.valoratual  
FROM crm_processo P 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT descricao FROM crm_processo_atividade 
           WHERE idprocesso = P.idprocesso    
           AND idatividade = P.idatividadeatual
           AND idatividade <> 2 ) AS PA           
     ON PA.idprocesso = P.idprocesso
LEFT JOIN (SELECT valoratual, 
             CASE descricao 
             WHEN '/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/' THEN 'Motivo Cancelamento'     
             END AS descricao
           FROM crm_processo_variavel 
           WHERE idprocesso = P.idprocesso 
           AND descricao IN ('/*MOTIVOCANCELAMENTO*/') ) AS PV
     ON PV.idprocesso = P.idprocesso
WHERE 
     P.status = 1 
     AND P.idprocedimento = 34
```

Comment: Deu certo @Pagotti. Obrigado. Vlw pelas dicas.